# Typescript: how to type variadic arguments?

Tags: typescript

Trying to convert this function to typescript:

```
const runProcess = (...proc) => {
  const proc = child_process.spawn(...proc, {
    stdio: ["ignore", "pipe", "pipe"],
  });
```

Can it be done? In this particular case, procs can be either a single string or a 2-tuple (how to represent this in TS?) made up of a string and an array of strings.

Comment: Yes it can be done.  Which type is `child_process.spawn` expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For creating a tuple, you just put the types inside of the square brackets in the order that they appear.  `[string, string[]]` is the type for a 2-tuple of a `string` and an array of strings (`string[]`).

Since we are spreading the arguments of `runProcess` and treating it like an array, we need to treat the other argument type - a single string - as a 1-tuple `[string]`.

We say that our args `proc` is either one of these two tuples: `[string] | [string, string[]]`.  Therefore we know that the first element in the args array is always a `string` and the second element is either `string[]` or `undefined`.  In order to call [`child_process.spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), we want to default to an empty array for the second argument if none is given.

That signature looks like:

```
const runProcess = (...proc: [string] | [string, string[]]) => {
    const [str, arr = []] = proc;
    const child = child_process.spawn(str, arr, {
        stdio: ["ignore", "pipe", "pipe"],
    });
}
```

But given that we are always dealing with exactly one or two arguments, I'm not sure that it really makes sense to spread the arguments as `...proc`.  Why not just have a required first argument and an optional second argument that defaults to an empty array?

```
const runProcess = (command: string, args: string[] = []) => {
    const proc = child_process.spawn(command, args, {
        stdio: ["ignore", "pipe", "pipe"],
    });
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/1WG09w)

Edit: as suggested by @Aleksey L., you can pass the spawn `args` as individual string arguments rather than as an array.

```
const runProcess = (command: string, ...args: string[]) => {
    const proc = child_process.spawn(command, args, {
        stdio: ["ignore", "pipe", "pipe"],
    });
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAYwBbADYBMD6YoQQUwGdC4AzXEOAcmTSxzyMKoG4BYAKE4QgDtD4UAK68ACrgLE4AXjgAKHiBABDXugBccAVGC8A5gBo4AOlPKoewpu269AbQC6AShkA%20OAG9OcH4j4C4BgQZRBQMbAkmY0IwZQB3XgUIJVV0I3NLIy8OX1ytGHRgCE07ACJgPV5ofFKjUrBgMBq6hqbShwNvXwBfJ3YObqA)

Comment: Sure, this allows defining the varargs as an array, but expanding it with the spread operator does not placate typescript: 

`TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
searchwidget_take2.ts:14:42 - error TS2556: Expected 1-3 arguments, but got 1 or more.` The error highlight is on the options object. It's not really going through and checking and seeing that the options object is intended to get interpreted as options. This could be an issue with the node types.

Comment: Ok that's why I asked what `spawn` was expecting.  Seems like it is expecting 1-3 arguments only, and the error is that the array can have infinitely many?  If that's the case then we need to be more specific in defining the second argument so that is has a limited length rather than just any array of strings.  Is that right?

Comment: My bad, I did not realize this was [a built-in function](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) so I didn't know how to call it.  I'll edit my code.  We have to pass the arguments to `spawn` separately.

Comment: Does my edit work for you?  I think it should work but I can't figure out how to import node types into the TS playground so I can't check it.

Comment: @LindaPaiste you can `import child_process from 'child_process';` in playground, it works

Comment: `args` could be defined as rest parameter, then default can be removed and args can be passed without defining the array on caller site https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAYwBbADYBMD6YoQQUwGdC4AzXEOAcmTSxzyMKoG4BYAKE4QgDtD4UAK68ACrgLE4AXjgAKHiBABDXugBccAVGC8A5gBo4AOlPKoewpu269AbQC6AShkA+OAG9OcH4j4C4BgQZRBQMbAkmY0IwZQB3XgUIJVV0I3NLIy8OX1ytGHRgCE07ACJgPV5ofFKjUrBgMBq6hqbShwNvXwBfJ3YObqA

Comment: @AlekseyL. I like that!

Comment: That last example is actually spectacularly elegant for this specific situation. What a great idea. Also, I suppose it's just a twist of fate that this node.js interface wasn't really made with typescript compatibility in mind. C'est la vie.